# php thumbnail Enlarge when click

Tags: php, html

Hi i'm making a online shop for a thesis, I want to know how to enlarge thumbnails when click. Like this one here in amazon.com
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00THKEKEQ/ref=s9_ri_gw_g421_i1/177-3641034-5833112?ie=UTF8&fpl=fresh&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=desktop-2&pf_rd_r=00MNMARHTQGGQG34P0MB&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=2091268582&pf_rd_i=desktop](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00THKEKEQ)

When the thumbnails in the side is click it enlarge to the main position

I have this code iffset

```
<form action='' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
     <input type='image' src='admin/product_images/$pro_image2' name='imgdetails1' class='imgdetails1' />
</form>
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['imgdetails1'])){
    echo"
        <input type='image' src='admin/product_images/$pro_image2'  class='imgdetails5' />";
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I want to enlarge the thumbnail image when clicked like in the amazon

Comment: If you want to dynamically open a large image you need JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run code dynamically on a page using PHP; you would have to refresh the page in order to re-run the script. In order to avoid doing this, JavaScript is used as it runs in the users browser making the site dynamic.

You could write this in pure JS or in jQuery but you might want to take a look at something like this: http://photoswipe.com/

Good luck!